# Update Mongoose Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

so basically I have this and I am trying to update the `STATUS` part of an array. 
However, everything I try does nothing. I have tried `findOneAndUpdate` also. I am trying to identify the specific item in the array by the number then update the status part of that specific array
(Sorry for formatting, I have no idea how to do that on the site yet ...) (Full code can be found here: https://sourceb.in/0811b5f805)

Code

```js
const ticketObj = {
  number: placeholderNumber,
  userID: message.author.id,
  message: m.content,
  status: 'unresolved'
}

let tnumber = parseInt(args[1])
let statuss = "In Progress"
await Mail.updateOne({
  "number": tnumber
}, { $set: { "status": statuss } })
```

Schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const mailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  guildID: { type: String, required: true },
  ticketCount: { type: Number, required: true },
  tickets: { type: Array, default: [] }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mail', mailSchema)
```

Comment: What is the error if any?

Comment: No error. It just doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `` Mail.updateOne({"guildID": message.guild.id}, {$set: {`tickets.${tnumber}.status`: statuss}}) ``

or for all objects in array:

`Mail.updateOne({"guildID": message.guild.id}, {$set: {'tickets.$[].status': statuss}})`

Also, you need to create a schema for the `tickets`, as it is described in [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

`one important reason to use subdocuments is to create a path where there would otherwise not be one to allow for validation over a group of fields`

Comment: How would I do that for multiple objects? That's the only reason I haven't tried that yet ...

Comment: Mongo has the special operator for the query inside an array.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]

Comment: Thats okay! Having the `tickets.${tnumber}.status` breaks everything though for some reason when its surrounded by the ` but not '

Comment: Maybe your js compiler does not support es5/es6 features, try this  instead `"tickets." + tnumber + ".status"`

Comment: Nope ... It says its expecting a : now lol Before it was expecting a "Property assignment"

Comment: you need to put it in a some variable first.
`const query = {};
const key = "tickets." + tnumber + ".status"';
query[key] = statuss;

Mail.updateOne({"guildID": message.guild.id}, {$set: query})
`

Comment: also mongoose may require a schema for a ticket object.

Comment: a schema for the ticket object?